# Why does this parent element not fully contain its child?

Tags: html, css

When my browser window is maxmised this code works fine, the child is contained within the parent and the parent spans the width of the browser. However, when the browser window is smaller than the child elements width, the parent element fails to contain it (tested in chrome 20 and firefox 13)

http://jsfiddle.net/x9duU/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Example</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            #toolbar {
                background-color:#cccccc;
                padding:10px 0;
            }

            #nav {
                background-color:#00cccc;
                margin:0 auto;
                width:1000px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="toolbar">
            <div id="nav">NAVIGATION</div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I can solve the problem by floating the parent and giving it a minimum with of 100% but this seems wrong. What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#toolbar` is a blocklevel-element, which defaults to `width:100%` - 100% width regarding the parent element. This is the rule it obeys to, letting the child overflow in case it's width exceeds. You could tweak this by setting the overflow property.

However, if you want the parent div to take it's child's width into account set a min-width (which equals the width of the child) Important: you have to take possible margins and paddings into account (or change the box-model to border-box).

```
#toolbar {
   min-width:1000px;
}​
```

Comment: I did some reading up after I posted the question and realised my understanding of how blocklevel elements work was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most appropriate way to fix this is to [remove the 1000px `width` from `#nav`](http://jsfiddle.net/6jUKJ/) (what is it really doing there?).

Alternatively, giving `#toolbar` `overflow: hidden` would [achieve the same visual effect](http://jsfiddle.net/kSmEw/).

Comment: Eventually the #toolbar will have a background colour (spanning the page width) and the #nav will contain the site navigation centered on the page so it is not possible to remove the width

Answer (score 0):

Try min-width:1000px on your nav

```
 #nav {
        background-color:#00cccc;
        margin:0 auto;
        min-width:1000px;/*New style*/
    }​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        #toolbar {
            background-color:#cccccc;
            padding:10px 0;

            overflow: hidden;
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, I put the overflow on the wrong element.  Move it to #toolbar as in my edited answer.